# remove some specific characters from a set of files

Tags: java

I have a folder holding a set of files, where some lines in each file contain a specific character as consisted of #, $ and %. How can I just remove these characters from those files while keeping other contents exactly the same as before. How to do that in Java?

Comment: You're going to have to read the entire content of each file and replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with Java NIO.

```
Set<Path> paths = ... // get your file paths
// for each file
for (Path path : paths) { 
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path)); // read their content
    content = content.replace("$", "").replace("%", "").replace("#", ""); // replace the content in memory
    Files.write(path, content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING); // write the new content
}
```

I did not provide exception handling. Deal with that any way you want.

OR

If you are on Linux, use Java's `ProcessBuilder` to build a [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command to transform the content.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to stream the files line-by-line? This is likely to cause an OOME even with fairly small files...

Comment: @BoristheSpider In cases where the file is big, sure. But you will have to write to a different file while you are reading and rename it (overwrite the original) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
files = new File("MyDirectory").list();
for (file : files) {
  tempfile = new File(file.getName() + ".tmp", "w");
  do {
    buffer = file.read(some_block_size);
    buffer.replace(targetCharacters, replacementCharacter);
    tempfile.write(buffer);
  } while (buffer.size > 0);
  file.delete();
  tempfile.rename(file.getName());
}
```